# On Bretschneider's generalization of Ptolemy's theorem

Tags: geometry, reference-request, euclidean-geometry, online-resources

Mathematician [Carl Anton Bretschneider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Anton_Bretschneider) (1808–1878), from Gotha (Germany), carried out the following generalization of [Ptolemy’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem), which refers to the product of diagonals in a convex quadrilateral.

> Assume that ABCD is a convex quadrilateral. Then
> $$AC^2\cdot{
> BD^2} = AB^2\cdot{CD^2} + AD^2\cdot{BC^2} − 2\cdot{AB}\cdot{BC}\cdot{CD}\cdot{DA}\cdot{cos{(\angle{B} + \angle{D})}}$$

is valid, where $\angle{B}$ and $\angle{D}$ are the inner angles at the vertices of the given quadrilateral.

I have taken this generalization from [this article](http://elib.mi.sanu.ac.rs/files/journals/tm/44/tmn44p57-70.pdf), but it does not cite the source. So my question is: **what is the original source of this generalization?**

Comment: Does he belong to mathematicians' Gotha ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, as far as I know, Bretschneider was from Gotha.

Comment: "The almanach of Gotha" was recording famous people (like "Who's who")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source appears to be [Bretschneider, C. A. *Untersuchung der trigonometrischen Relationen des geradlinigen Viereckes.* Archiv der Math. 2, 225-261, 1842](https://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/view/bsb10593862?page=237).

The equation you're asking about is the first equation of group 32 on pg 237.

[image]

The terms are defined on pg 227, except for $\psi$, which is defined on pg 234.

The paper presents a large number of formulae in a similar vein that relate to the so-called complete quadrangle.